# Visual Studio lightbulb keyboard shortcut

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio, productivity, resharper

I am trying to make working with Visual Studio more productive, but hitting a common problem which requires a mouse to resolve. To see a **Quick fix** (a "lightbulb" suggestion), you can use a <kbd>Ctrl + .</kbd> shortcut. Unfortunately, this does not work when there is a "hammer" suggestion on the same line.

As an example, consider the following line.

[image: Hammer suggestion]

Hitting the shortcut invokes the "hammer":

[image: Hammer suggestion invoked via shortcut]

However, when I hover my mouse over the enum name, I get the lightbulb:

[image: Lightbulb]

Is there a way to open the "lightbulb" via a keyboard shortcut or maybe loop through all suggestion types available?

**Update**
Note I am using ReSharper as well.

Comment: The hammer icon is from Resharper I believe.  From what I read, Alt + Enter should open the menu of all the context options to which you should be able to navigate using arrow keys